# How to run a Java Sesame Application From Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sesame

I am very new to Java Sesame. I am trying to start with something very simple. Here are the steps I have done so far:

1- Deployed the `war` files: `openrdf-sesame` and `openrdf-workbench` in `Tomcat Manager`.
2- created a repository called `Sample` through `openrdf-workbench`
3- In Eclipse, I have got this code:

```
import org.openrdf.repository.Repository;
import org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryConnection;
import org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException;
import org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException;
import org.openrdf.repository.manager.RemoteRepositoryManager;
import java.io.File;
import org.openrdf.rio.RDFFormat;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openrdf.OpenRDFException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RDF{

public void create() throws RepositoryConfigException, RepositoryException
{


    String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame";
    RemoteRepositoryManager manager = new RemoteRepositoryManager(serverUrl);
    manager.initialize();
    Repository repository = manager.getRepository("Sample");
    File file = new File("Sample_Sesame.json");
    String baseURI = "file://Sample_Sesame.json";


    try {
       RepositoryConnection con = repository.getConnection();
       try {
          con.add(file, baseURI, RDFFormat.N3);
          URL url = new URL("/Users/Documents/newsample/folder/Sample_Sesame.json");
          con.add(url, url.toString(), RDFFormat.RDFXML);
           }
       finally { con.close(); }
      }
    catch (OpenRDFException e) { // handle exception }
    catch (IOException e) { // handle io exception }
}
}
```

As being a beginner in Java Sesame, I have two questions, since I created the repository in `openrdf-workbench`, how can I execute the above code in Eclipse?

My second question: is this the right way of adding an RDF statement into the repository? The file I am having is a JSON file as below: `Sample_Sesame.json`

```
{
 "http://example.org/about" : 
{
   "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title": [ { "type" : "literal" , "value" : "Rich's Homepage" } ]
}
}
```

Your assistance would be sincerely more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute your code, you simply create a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RDF rdf = new RDF();
    rdf.create();
}
```

Your RDF seems to be in the RDF/JSON format which seems to be supported by Sesame 2.7, so you have to specify the [RDFFormat.RDFJSON](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/rio/RDFFormat.html#RDFJSON).

Alternatively, you could convert your file to some other, universally accepted format such as N-Triples. Have a look at http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/ and try to copy paste your sample json there. For input select RDF/JSON and for output N-Triples.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. One more question, please. Is it possible to run the application by selecting Run on Server or is there another effective way to run it? Will the statement be added to the repository after running the application?

Comment: Why would you want to run the application on server? Just run it as any ordinary Java application choosing simple Run in Eclipse. Yes, the statements should be in the repository after you run the code. You can verify it via the workbench UI by exploring the repo or by issuing a SPARQL query.

Comment: OK. I run it as application. Unfortunately, I have an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod. I will try to fix it and let you know soon. Thank you for very much for your concern.

Comment: You just need to include some Sesame dependencies, have a look here: http://sesame-general.435816.n3.nabble.com/Sesame-dependencies-td4026245.html

Comment: I am having Java 1.5. It is a bit old. I am searching for the proper jars that suit the Java version in my local machine.

Comment: At the moment, I am having this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory. However, I have added all the jar files as: Add External Jars, but it is still not working and shows me the same error. Any idea, please?

Comment: Well, you're clearly missing some more libraries, at least some logging like logback and slf4j: http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html the paragraph about logback-classic.

Comment: I think the problem is now which libraries suit the JDK 1.5. I am trying figure this out. I have added the library slf4j-1.7.0.tar.gz and logback-1.0.11 for logback-classic. I am still having the same error.

Comment: Well, it would be better for you to use a more recent Java version. But if the problem really was the Java version then the error message would likely be different. You would also not have many of these problems if you used Maven. It's not difficult to set up.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your assistance. It seems it is running at the moment. I tested it with the mesthod isOpen(). At this point, I need to understand how things work with adding statements and JSON. Your support is very much appreciated.